# Java - Retrieving a web page with authorization

Tags: java, web-crawler, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to retrieve a github web page  using a java code, for this I used following code.

```
String startingUrl = "https://github.com/xxxxxx";
URL url = new URL(startingUrl );
HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
uc.connect();
String line = null;
StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();
try{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        tmp.append(line);
    }       
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
}
```

However, the page I received here is different from what I observe in browser after login to github. I tried sending authorization header as following, but it didn't worked either.

```
uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic encodexxx");
```

How can I retrieve the same page that I see when I logged in?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that the site actually make use of HTTP Basic Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you more on this, because I don't know what are you getting, but most common issue for web crawlers is the fact that website owners mostly **don't like web crawlers**. Thus, you should behave like regular user - your browser for instance. Open your browser inspection element (press f12) when you are reaching some website and see what your browser send in request, then try to mimic it: For example, add `Host, Referer`, etc in your header. You need to experiment on this.

Also, good to know - some website owners will use advanced techniques (so they will block you to access their site), some won't stop you crawling on their website. Some will let you do what you want. Most fair option is to check *www.somedomain.com/**robots.txt*** and there is list of endpoints that are allowed for scraping and those that shouldn't be allowed.